# Running TF.exe from TeamCity fails. Same script from same server and using same user as agent succeeds

Tags: cmd, azure-devops, teamcity

I need to push some code to a TFS server (TFS Source control) as part of our build process. I'm calling TF.exe with the /Login: parameter and a service account's details. If I run this batch file locally as my user, or on the build agent as the Local System (the agent runs as this user) it works fine. The credentials are accepted. If I put the same script into TeamCity's "Custom Script" build step, the script fails with the error "TF30063: You are not authorized to access [ServerName]\tfs\DefaultCollection.
Any ideas?

```
    mkdir Workspace
cd Workspace
tf workspace -new CodeWorkspace;username -noprompt -server:[ServerName]/tfs/DefaultCollection /login:"username,password"
tf workfold -map $/"Database Dependencies" . -workspace:CodeWorkspace -server:[ServerName]/tfs/DefaultCollection /login:"username,password"
tf get /force /all -recursive -noprompt  /login:"username,password"
tf checkout MercuryDatabaseShared.dacpac MercuryPortal.dacpac PhoenixDatabase.dacpac  /login:"username,password"
tf checkin MercuryDatabaseShared.dacpac MercuryPortal.dacpac PhoenixDatabase.dacpac  /login:"username,password" /noprompt /force /comment:"***FROM TEAMCITY - %build.number%***" 
tf workfold -unmap . -workspace:CodeWorkspace /login:"username,password"
tf workspace -delete CodeWorkspace -noprompt -server:[ServerName]/tfs/DefaultCollection  /login:"username,password"
cd ..
RMDIR /S /Q Workspace
```

Comment: Why are you putting build outputs into source control? That is a fantastically bad practice.

Comment: They're dacpacs which contain the schema of our Application databases so that our MI team has up-to-date references in their projects.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you can execute the tf commands successful manunally on the agent machine but failed when build by TeamCity, please check if the agent configuration for TeamCity use run as the same account as your local machine. And you can troubleshoot with below aspects:

- When selecting Service Account for Agent after installing, check if you run TeamCity agent under a user account.

  [image]
- Double check in the TeamCity web UI -> Agents Tab -> click the agent -> Agent Parameters Tab -> Environment Variables Tab -> make sure the domain and the username  are consistent with the domain and username you are login the TFS.

  [image]

  [image]
- When using `/login:username,password` option for tf commands, please use the `domain\username` and the login password instead. Such as

  ```
  tf workspaces /collection:http://tfsServer:8080/tfs/DefaultCollection /login:"fareast\myname,password"
  ```

Comment: I'd convinced myself that I'd already tried with the domain in the Login parameter, but obviously not. Everything working now. Thanks very much!